# How to use the InvokeMethod activity to add a string to a generic list using Workflow Foundation 4

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have a Workflow Foundation 4 activity that has a InvokeMethod that is configured to call the `Add` method on an instance of type `IList(Of String)`, providing a parameter of type `String`.

Running it gives me this error though:

```
'IList`1' does not have a public instance method named 'Add' matching the parameter
types, generic type arguments, and generic type constraints supplied to InvokeMethod
'InvokeMethod'.
```

I've tried all settings for the InvokeMethod activity I could think of, to no avail.

So the question is: how do I make the InvokeMethod add the string parameter to the generic list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the AddToCollection activity?

Comment: Thanks, great to see there is such a simple solution.